# How can I set up a devserver proxy in Vue, but have it ignore local php files?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a devserver proxy setup in VueJS that allows me to talk to my website for APIS and get around CORS problems when working in my local devbuild.

However, with this setup, if the requested file exists locally, the local devserver proxy doesn't get the file from my website (which I want it to do for PHP files), it instead tries to load the local PHP file via the Vue devserver.

my vue.config.js file looks like this:

```
 module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ],
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'https://www.example.com',
  }
}
```

Is it possible to set up exclusions for specific files, or specific file types (ie PHP files)?